# insert string into middle of antoher string at an specific, but unknown point - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

i have been struggling with this one for a couple of days

i have a block of string which is html , which i am loading into a web view as html text. what i would like to do is insert an image aprox halfway into the string, but do it at the start or end of a paragraph , so i keep the overall format of the string

for example, if i have

```
<p>
some text 
<p>
would like to insert image here
<p>
more text
```

is there any way i can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load webview using below string

```
NSString* mTheBackgroundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo_s28" ofType:@"png"];
    mTheBackgroundPath = [  mTheBackgroundPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
    mTheBackgroundPath = [ mTheBackgroundPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    mTheBackgroundPath = [@"file://" stringByAppendingString:mTheBackgroundPath];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>
                            some text 
                            <p>
                            %@
                            <p>
                            more text",mTheBackgroundPath];
```